# MySQL Display Image

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm wondering if someone can help me please, I'm a new to MySQL.

I have a two tables:

Table One 
div_attachments fields: ID Fkey Images Time

Table Two: 
div_submissions fields: ID Name Phone Email

I'm using a php page in Joomla to display the data. I want to display the Images from div_attachments on the submissions page which uses the table div_submissions.

*I think its something like:*
SELECT * FROM $div_attachments AND $div_submissions
WHERE FKEY==ID

Can someone please help with the put together the query that I need to display the image in submissions?

Thanks.

Here is what I tried

```
$data = array();
foreach(explode(',',$item->attachments) as $value):
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query= $db->getQuery(true);
$query
  >select('image')
  >from('`#__div_attachments`')-
  >where('fkey = ' .$value);
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
if(count($results)){
$data[] = $results[0]->image;
}
endforeach;
echo implode(',',$data); ?>
```

Comment: first, remove the `$` from your table names in the query. And no, sorry, we're not here to teach you php or sql. if you have some actual code, we'll try to help fix that, but you've got to learn the basics on your own.

Comment: thats interesting you say that because i see similar post likes this all over this site and people are willing to help out.

Answer (score 0):

"I want to display the Images from div_attachments on the submissions page which uses the table div_submissions."

Have you tried just selecting the image from div_attachments by id?

Comment: I have but it's my understanding that I need to match the ID and FKEY so that the images for the corresponding submission display properly. Otherwise all the image will show up.

Comment: You can run a single statement that would query what you need, but if it isn't required, you can run two queries.  First get all the submission entries then query the attachments based on the result of the first query.  Once you get that working maybe someone can help put the two sql statements together.  I'd put it here if I know it by heart. Look up Select and Union.